# Making 2 spans to expand to fit into li width

Tags: html, css

I want my two `span` to expand to fit into my  `li` element.

In the original project I use bootstrap and jquery too, but as example this will be enough:

http://jsfiddle.net/d5pc8Lp3/

```
<ol>
    <li><span>Element-Name</span><span>></span></li>
    <li><span>I-want-to-fit-like-the-li-width</span><span>></span></li>
</ol>
```

The first `span` in the  `li` element is the element name, and the second `span` is the "navigator".

I want that the first `span` width fill the rest of the `li` element.

Comment: Any Fiddle That you have tried it out??

Comment: i tried min-width, width: 100%, but nothing happend

And fiddle is in the post btw.

Comment: U want the span tags to have a fixed width or all the Element-Name span tags to be of same width and height?

Comment: try display: inline-block;

Comment: I want them to be as wide, as the widest element-name span (so fit the existing li element they are in)

Comment: Note `>` is invalid. Use `&gt;` instead.

Comment: Thx for the note Oriol!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use flexbox:

```css
li {
  display: flex; /* Magic begins */
}
li > :first-child {
  flex-grow: 1; /* Grow to fill available space */
}
```

```css
ol > li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: flex;
}
li > span:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
li > span {
  padding: 5px;
  color: #c7c7c7;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  background: #fff;
}
li > span:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}
li > span:nth-child(2) {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
li > span:nth-child(1):hover {
  border: 1px #1c1c1c solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li > span:nth-child(2):hover {
  border: 1px #1c1c1c solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><span>Element-Name</span><span>&gt;</span></li>
  <li><span>I-want-to-fit-like-the-li-width</span><span>&gt;</span></li>
  <li><span>My-width-doenst-fit</span><span>&gt;</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This worked very well! Thank you. Will confirm after the 5 min.

Comment: Flex is a beast. It started out very rough, but it's growing: both in features, and in my heart.

Answer (score 5):

You could go for `calc()`:

```
li > span:nth-child(1) {
    margin-right: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    width: calc(90% - 15px);
    display: inline-block;
}

li > span:nth-child(2) {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d5pc8Lp3/3/

Comment: This is very nice too, anyway i didnt know the calc() statement and needet it several times. Thank you too!